# How to set overflow conditions in Assembly Language X86

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following two functions. nCr which computes the factorial of an int. nCr calls another function which is factorial which does the computation. As the numbers get larger, there is an overflow. I need to set up overflow conditions. I'm trying to use JO (jump on overflow) but I am having problems when I compile it. The bold is where I put my conditions. Where is my mistake?

```
_nCr:  
    pushl   %ebp  
    movl    %esp, %ebp  
    subl    $56, %esp  
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax  
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
```

**

> ```
> call      _factorial  
>
>     cmp    $0, %eax
>     je      L22
>     cmpl    $0, %eax
>     jne      L23
>    L22: 
>     movl $0, %eax
>     leave 
>     ret
> ```

**

```
    L23:
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)  
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax  
    addl    $1, %eax  
    movl    %eax, (%esp)  
    call    _factorial  
    movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)  
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax  
    notl    %eax  
    addl    8(%ebp), %eax  
    movl    %eax, (%esp)  
    call    _factorial  
    movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)  
    movl    -16(%ebp), %eax  
    movl    %eax, %edx  
    imull   -20(%ebp), %edx  
    movl    %edx, -28(%ebp)  
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax  
    movl    %eax, %edx  
    sarl    $31, %edx  
    idivl   -28(%ebp)  
    leave  
    ret  

_factorial:  
    pushl   %ebp  
    movl    %esp, %ebp  
    subl    $16, %esp  
    movl    $1, -8(%ebp)  
    movl    $1, -4(%ebp)  
    jmp L3  
L4:   
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
```

**

> imull      -4(%ebp), %eax
> jo      L2

**

```
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)  
    addl    $1, -4(%ebp) 
L2:
   movl   $0, %eax
   leave
   ret**

L3:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax  
    cmpl    8(%ebp), %eax  
    jle L4  
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax  
    leave  
    ret
```

Basically if the overflow is detected then the functions should return 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect overflow conditions in Assembly Langauge X86](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797473/how-to-detect-overflow-conditions-in-assembly-langauge-x86)

Comment: I don't see anything in bold.  Could you be more specific about the problems you have when you compile?

Comment: I separated the sections and used **. The first block is after the first call to factorial and the second block is when the ints are being multiplied. Problem I get is " floating point exception (core dumped). and when I try to alter it my program would not work. the overflow would occur at 13! but it wouldn't even run if the int I imputed was 2

Comment: `imul` never causes an overflow. This happens in the `idiv` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

First, if your values are limited to 32 bits, it's weird to use cycle for factorial because factorial(12) is the last value which fits into 32 bits. So, it's simpler to implement factorial as table lookup for values between 1 and 12, and return 0 for any other value.

If you still want to use cycle for this (well, it can be homework requirement), take care on high part of product (by imull) which is placed in %edx. It shall be equal to extension of sign of %eax, otherwise product can't fit in 32 bits. Two example variants for this:

```
mov %eax, %ecx
sarl $31, $ecx
cmp %edx, %ecx
jne overflow_found
```

or

```
mov %edx, %ecx
cltd
cmp %edx, %ecx
jne overflow_found
```

I'm also confused where your program gets numeric overflow. The only suspicious place is "idiv", but as soon as %edx is extension of sign of %eax, this can happen if divisor if zero. You should explicitly check divisor value before calling divide, neither compiler nor processor will do it.